# Tag permalink wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am creating an ad site. For each ad, I would like the relevant page to have a url containing the phone number entered by the user when filling out the ad form. I have tried the various tags that manage permalinks, but none of them show the telephone number among the available tags.I would like to add a new tag, i.e. the author's telephone number, which I can add to the permalinks of listings. The question is this, the number that I would like to have inserted in the permalink structure must be the same as the number that the user enters in the form to request the publication of his or her ad. How can I do this, can anyone help me, I am using Listeo. Perhaps I could provide you with the theme or code.

I don't know how to do it, but a new tag must be inserted in the permalinks phone number, clearly a custom value for each user and ad.